# Why my server not sending anything to my client

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I already try to run my server in background and it shown under ps, i can see my Server running, but when i try run Client, by right server should write to client saying " Successfully connected to server" but nothing is being output there.

My server code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#ifndef AF_LOCAL
#define AF_LOCAL AF_UNIX
#endif
#ifndef PF_LOCAL
#define PF_LOCAL PF_UNIX
#endif

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int serverFd;
int clientFd;
int serverLen;
int clientLen;
string message;
string serverSockAddrPtr;
struct sockaddr* serverSockAddressPnt;
struct sockaddr* clientSockAddressPnt;
struct sockaddr_un serverAddress;
struct sockaddr_un clientAddress;

cout << "" << endl;
cout << "Running server program 'css' ...... " << endl;
cout << "" << endl;


// SOCKET CREATION PART - SERVER
serverFd = socket (AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

/* Set domain type */
serverAddress.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;

/* Set name */
strcpy (serverAddress.sun_path, "CServer");


/* GET SIZE OF Server Addres */
serverLen = sizeof serverAddress;
/* GET SIZE OF Client Addres */
clientLen = sizeof clientAddress;

/* Get Server Sock Address Pointer*/
serverSockAddressPnt = (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress;
/* Get Client Sock Address Pointer*/
clientSockAddressPnt = (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress;

/* Create file */
bind (serverFd, serverSockAddressPnt , serverLen);

/* listen for connection */
listen (serverFd,5);


cout << "" << endl;
// SOCKET CREATION END - SERVER


while(1)
{
//accept client connection
clientFd = accept(serverFd, clientSockAddressPnt, (socklen_t*)&clientLen);

if(clientFd >= 0)
{
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        message="Successfully connected to the server";
        write(clientFd,message.c_str(),strlen(message.c_str())+1);
        close(clientFd);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        close(clientFd);
}

}

return 0;
}
```

My client code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#define DEFAULT_PROTOCOL 0
#ifndef AF_LOCAL
#define AF_LOCAL AF_UNIX
#endif
#ifndef PF_LOCAL
#define PF_LOCAL PF_UNIX
#endif

using namespace std;

/* READ LINE FUNCTION*/
int readLine (int fd,char* str)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = read(fd,str,1);
    }while(n>0&& *str++ != 0);
    return(n>0);
}
/* READ LINE FUNCTION END*/


/* READ SERVER FUNCTION*/
void readServer (int fd)
{
    char str[500];
    while (readLine(fd,str))
    {
        printf("%s",str);
    }
}
/* READ SERVER FUNCTION END*/




int main()
{

int clientFd,serverLen,result;
struct sockaddr_un serverAddress;
struct sockaddr* serverSockAddressPnt;

/* Get Server Sock Address Pointer*/
serverSockAddressPnt = (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress;

/* GET SIZE OF Server Addres */
serverLen = sizeof serverAddress;

clientFd = socket (AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
serverAddress.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
strcpy (serverAddress.sun_path,"CServer");

do
{
    // a loop to keep trying till connected.
    result=connect(clientFd,serverSockAddressPnt,serverLen);
    if(result==-1)
    {
        //wait for 1 second to retry
        sleep(1);
    }

}while(result==-1);
readServer (clientFd);
close (clientFd);
exit(0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Attach gdb to the server program and see whats going on.

Comment: Besides debugging in GDB stepping through either the server or client code, you could also add more output. For example if the client connects successfully you could print it to the console in both the client and server, but more importantly print output when something _fails_, together with the error code.

Comment: This is not C but some mixture of C and C++. Don't do that it is not worth it, decide on which language you want to use and stick to it.

Comment: One thing you should try is to set the `sun_family` member of the `sockaddr_un` structure properly to `AF_LOCAL`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `serverAddress` variable is not initialized. I didn't check this but most likely `serverAddress.sun_path` is a pointer to `char`, which then is just initialized with a random value. This

```
strcpy (serverAddress.sun_path,"CServer");
```

then overwrites some arbitrary memory. The correct way to do this in C is

```
struct sockaddr_un serverAddress = { 0 };
```

Generally:

- Always, yes always, initialize all variables. Don't worry about some minor improvements in efficiency that not doing so might bring. It is usually not worth it and in any case you are not yet there. (Here a proper initialization with `0` would have your program crash nicely from the start.)
- Always compile with all warning options on.
- Don't mix C and C++. They have subtle differences that are not worth it. In particular here you gain nothing from using C++.

Comment: Especially like the "crash nicely from the start" part.

Comment: I think you should check out the [`sockaddr_un`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) structure, the `sun_path` member is a proper array.

Answer (score 1):

Pl. add some more error handling to your code, as Joachim suggested.
The most likely cause of the problem is you are binding, but before that you are not deleting the socket file (Assuming the file already exists since you are experimenting) which is to be bound (that is "CServer").

So even if bind is failing, but since errors are hot handled, the server starts (you can see it by ps command). And your client cannot connect even if you can see the server running using ps. So you can solve this by unlinking(deleting)  the socket file before bind.

```
unlink("CServer");
bind (serverFd, serverSockAddressPnt , serverLen);
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Sharing a link for a  tutorial, which I found 
http://tkhanson.net/cgit.cgi/misc.git/plain/unixdomain/Unix_domain_sockets.html

Another observation is that your code will produce zombies(defunct processes ps command in Linux will show defunct  entries), since you have not added a zombie handler.

A temporary solution, I would suggest,  is that pl. add the line below (assuming Linux) before your socket call in the server program, (also include signal.h) to ignore SIGCHLD(death of child signal).The zombies will not be seen.

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Client does not know which server to connect to.
You do `struct sockaddr* serverSockAddressPnt;` But this will only define `serverSockAddressPnt` as a pointer to `struct sockaddr`. but it is supposed to be initialized or assigned the ip address of the server to connect.

Comment: The OP assigns the pointer to `&serverAddress` so it is initialized properly.